# How to check if given component has been loaded to a current page in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I need to check if JoomGallery has been loaded to a page ( "option=com_joomgallery" in URL), to load module in this condition. Parsing URL is not a good idea. (in PHP )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (JRequest::getCmd( 'option' ) == 'com_joomgallery'){
        echo ' JoomGalery extension in use';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Advanced Module Manager for module control. This will allow you to load modules conditionally whether or not you have a menu item for the component or not.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/modules-management/10307